# MS Project compatibility and Office 365

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I have two questions for the experts on MS Project

1. I have heard that Microsoft will now be releasing updates (from Sept 2018) for O365 without testing them for MS Project 2010. Is this True? Also, will they stop testing for MS Project 2013 too?
2. Can we connect MS Project 2013 to Project server 2010?

Comment: Your first question should be directed at Microsoft, not us.

Comment: And what about the second?

Comment: The second seems fine to me, though I myself am unable to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect Microsoft Project 2013 to Project Server 2010, no.

I don't know how O365 updates are planned, but Microsoft Project Server 2010 and Microsoft Project Professional 2010 are both no longer eligible for mainstream support since 2015 (meaning only security updates are released for these products, unless you pay Microsoft for a hotfix). Extended Support will end in 2020, after that point no support will be available. Since these things can sometimes take a while to be approved and budgeted, I would advise you to start planning for a migration.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20Project%202010